# Jenkins ArtifactDeployer plugin How to ignore the source directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifacts

I'm using Jenkins to build compile some CSS/JS from a repo. And then I use ArtifactDeployer to move files to a remote folder in the web server. For reasons out of my control, the repo has an extra folder that I won't need in the server.
[Config Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jec5E.png)

In this example, I want to copy the folders js/ and styles/ that are in the "extrafolder" folder. But I don't need to "extrafolder" in the destination path.

Right now I get: "\remote\basefolder\extrafolder\js...." but I need "\remote\basefolder\js...."

I tried setting the Basedir to "basefolder" but the plugin can't find the js/styles folders there